# Uploading CSV in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I have this python code:

```
from psycopg2 import Error

connection = psycopg2.connect(host='xxxx.amazonaws.com',
                       dbname='xxxxxx',
                       user='xxxxxx',
                       password='xxxxxx')
cursor = connection.cursor()


cursor.execute('''create table book2(ISBN VARCHAR NOT NULL,
Title VARCHAR NOT NULL,
Author VARCHAR NOT NULL,
Year VARCHAR NOT NULL);''')


f = open(r'C:\Users\hanlewi\Documents\GitHub\lecture4\project1\try3\books.csv', 'r')
cursor.copy_from(f, 'book2', sep=',', null=' ')
f.close()
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "import.py", line 18, in <module>
    cursor.copy_from(f, 'book2', sep=',', null=' ')
psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY book2, line 5: "553803700,"I, Robot",Isaac Asimov,1950"
```

I no its because this ("I, Robot") has has quotes but i dont know how to fix my code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

`copy_from` in psycopg2 uses the text format to import CSV. You need to use the csv format. For more information on differences see:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-copy.html

To get this to work you will need to use [copy_expert](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html?highlight=copy_expert#cursor.copy_expert):

copy_expert(sql, file, size=8192)

"
Submit a user-composed COPY statement. The method is useful to handle all the parameters that PostgreSQL makes available (see COPY command documentation). ..."

Something along lines of :

`cur.copy_expert("COPY book2 FROM STDIN WITH CSV", f)`

the `WITH CSV` will take care of properly quoting the text with the delimiter(','). From sql_copy line above:

"
CSV Format

(...)

The values in each record are separated by the DELIMITER character. If the value contains the delimiter character, the QUOTE character, the NULL string, a carriage return, or line feed character, then the whole value is prefixed and suffixed by the QUOTE character, and any occurrence within the value of a QUOTE character or the ESCAPE character is preceded by the escape character. You can also use FORCE_QUOTE to force quotes when outputting non-NULL values in specific columns."

Comment: Adrian, Now I have no error but when I run python import.py nothing happens nothing shows in database no table or anything

Comment: nevermind i got it to work doing something different...thanks

Comment: If nothing showed in the database it is probably because you did not issue a connection.commit().